# Cómo encontrar eficientemente los vértices de cada polígono y solucionar un dibujado lento de OpenGL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, opengl

Estoy Usando tao framework para cargar un objeto 3D, almacenarlo, y después leer las listas en las que éste se guardó; pero el dibujado es muy lento.

Lo que presiento es que tengo demasiados ciclos para encontrar los vértices de cada polígono, pero desafortunadamente no he encontrado otro método para hacer esto.

¿Cómo sería una forma eficiente de encontrar los vértices y de ese modo hacer un dibujado de muchos poligonos en OpenGL?

Este es el fragmento del código que estoy utilizando:

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CARASRow.Count; i++)
    {
        List<int> FilaBuffer = new List<int>(CARASRow[i]); //fila buffer son los indices de caras por renglon
        List<int> FilaBuffer2 = new List<int>(FilaDeIndicesDeNormales[i]);

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POLYGON);
        for (int j = 0; j < FilaBuffer.Count; j++)
        {
            Gl.glColor3d(0.635, 0.635, 0.666);
            Gl.glNormal3d(NormalesX[FilaBuffer2[j] - 1], NormalesY[FilaBuffer2[j] - 1], NormalesZ[FilaBuffer2[j] - 1]);
            Gl.glVertex3d((VerticeX[FilaBuffer[j] - 1])/(100), (VerticeY[FilaBuffer[j] - 1])/(100), (VerticeZ[FilaBuffer[j] - 1])/(100));
        }

        Gl.glEnd();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

Comment: Alberto: esta pregunta es demasiado amplia. Date por favor una vuelta por [tour] y [ask] para entender cómo formular preguntas respondibles. Después, dale a [edit] y actualiza tu pregunta con preguntas más concretas, tus hipótesis, etc.

Comment: **Alberto** bienvenido a la comunidad. Toma el consejo de **fedorqui**. Tu algoritmo muestra la respuesta o no puedes verla por causa del tiempo que demora?

Comment: No se como esta el codigo completo pero hacer `new List<int>` durante el render penaliza mucho el codigo, eso podrias pre-allocarlo, sin duda haria tu proceso mas performante.

Comment: **Lazarok** Solo es muy lento al momento del dibujado

Comment: **Emanuel** Lo hago de esa manera porque la lista debe estar limpia, pero si la limpio despues de usarla tambien se limpia en la lista general que guarda todos los vertices.